# jquery FullCalendar block adding more events

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

how to block possibility to add more events to one day if there is already one event ??

i read all docs but didnt find answer [FullCalendar docs](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

Little dirty but did the trick

```
var css_class = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
$(this).removeClass(css_class[2]);
```